# boost regex formatter, how to use a custom function

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

Well how do I invoke a custom formatting function when calling boost::regex_replace?

My code is as following:

```
template <typename T>
std::string fmt(boost::match_results<T> match) {
    auto str = match[1];
    if (str == ".") {
        return "\".\"";
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
void __ConvertEscapeChar(std::string& action, std::string regex) {
    boost::regex re(regex);
    action = boost::regex_replace(action, re, &fmt, boost::regex_constants::match_all);
}
```

however it shows an error, "could not deduce template argument for __fmt". - Well what IS T actually?

Comment: Your function names are invalid.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Meh changed... But that dosen't really change anything.. (really need to a new PREfix to identify local functions now).

Comment: It changes your code to valid C++, other than your current error.

Comment: If by "local functions" you mean a function that shouldn't be visible outside the current compilation unit (.cc/.o file), you can put it in an anonymous namespace: `namespace { ConvertEscapeChar(...) {...} }`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the flexibility of using a template in your `fmt` function for some reason that isn't obvious here, try this instead:

```
std::string fmt(boost::smatch match)
```